# How to use s3a with Apache spark 2.2(hadoop 2.8) in the Spark Submit?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to access the `S3` data from spark using the spark 2.2.0 built using hadoop 2.8 version, I am using the `/jars/hadoop-aws-2.8.3.jar`, `/jars/aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.6.jar` and `/jars/aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.6.jar` in the `classpath`

I get the following exception

```
         java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StorageStatistics
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
            at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2134)
            at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2099)
            at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.hasMetadata(DataSource.scala:301)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:344)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:441)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
            at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
            at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
            at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
            at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
            at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.StorageStatistics
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            ... 27 more
```

Then I added the hadoop-common jar to the `classpath` from spark installation directory `/sparkinstallation/jars/hadoop-common-2.8.3.jar`, now I get the following error:

```
        java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableCounterLong.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/metrics2/MetricsInfo;J)V from class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInstrumentation
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInstrumentation.streamCounter(S3AInstrumentation.java:194)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInstrumentation.streamCounter(S3AInstrumentation.java:216)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInstrumentation.<init>(S3AInstrumentation.java:139)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:174)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2669)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.hasMetadata(DataSource.scala:301)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:344)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:441)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
            at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
            at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
            at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
            at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
            at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can somebody help if I am missing something ?

I have referred to the link - [How to use s3 with Apache spark 2.2 in the Spark shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45756554/how-to-use-s3-with-apache-spark-2-2-in-the-spark-shell), but didn't help

Comment: See the troubleshooting guide here about version dependencies https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.3/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to add the dependency to your `spark-submit` command as below, which will downloads all the dependencies required. If you just add a jar, you may still have some other dependencies missing:

```
 spark-shell --packages "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3"
 spark-submit --packages "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3"
```

Another way is to bundle the dependencies into your job jar file, then use normal `spark-sbumit`

Comment: Thanks @BinziCao - This helped. I am going with the second option of bundling the dependencies